# How to enforce carousel-caption text color setting during slide animation?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Can anyone tell me what's going on here with Bootstrap 5?

Would love to `z-index` my way out of this text color change happening on slide animation. Should stay `text-light`.

[image]

[image]

```css
.navbar-brand {
    margin: 0.4em 0 0.5em 0;
}
body > div.block.block-inverse.p-3 > div > nav > a > h4 {
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
.nav-item {
    font-family: "Work sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    line-height: 2;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
}
.carousel-caption {
    z-index: 1;
}
#myCarousel:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black, transparent);
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
#testimonials:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black, transparent);
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
.testimonial {
    padding: 14em 0 14em 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.82.0">
    <title>Carousel Template · Bootstrap v5.0</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/carousel/">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">


<meta name="theme-color" content="#7952b3">    
   
   <style>/* GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */
/* Padding below the footer and lighter body text */

body {
  padding-top: 3rem;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  color: #5a5a5a;
}


/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
/* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
.carousel-caption {
  bottom: 3rem;
  z-index: 10;
}

/* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
.carousel-item {
  height: 32rem;
}
.carousel-item > img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 32rem;
}


/* MARKETING CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */

/* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
.marketing .col-lg-4 {
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.marketing h2 {
  font-weight: 400;
}
/* rtl:begin:ignore */
.marketing .col-lg-4 p {
  margin-right: .75rem;
  margin-left: .75rem;
}
/* rtl:end:ignore */


/* Featurettes
------------------------- */

.featurette-divider {
  margin: 5rem 0; /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
}

/* Thin out the marketing headings */
.featurette-heading {
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1;
  /* rtl:remove */
  letter-spacing: -.05rem;
}


/* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

@media (min-width: 40em) {
  /* Bump up size of carousel content */
  .carousel-caption p {
    margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }

  .featurette-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .featurette-heading {
    margin-top: 7rem;
  }
}
</style>
   
  </head>
  <body>
    
<header>


<div class="block block-inverse p-3"
     style="background-color: #3883AC;
            background-image: url({% static 'img/startup-1.jpg' %});
            background-position: -40px 0px;
            background-repeat: repeat-x;">

  <div class="container">


  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Carousel</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  
  
  </div>
  </div>
  
</header>

<main>

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/></svg>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-start">
            <h1>Example headline.</h1>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide of the carousel.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/></svg>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide of the carousel.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/></svg>

        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-caption text-end">
            <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide of this carousel.</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>


  <!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes
  ================================================== -->
  <!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->

  <div class="container marketing">

    <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>

        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Some representative placeholder content for the three columns of text below the carousel. This is the first column.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>

        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>Another exciting bit of representative placeholder content. This time, we've moved on to the second column.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text></svg>

        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>And lastly this, the third column of representative placeholder content.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
      </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->


    <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">First featurette heading. <span class="text-muted">It’ll blow your mind.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">Some great placeholder content for the first featurette here. Imagine some exciting prose here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>

      </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7 order-md-2">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">Oh yeah, it’s that good. <span class="text-muted">See for yourself.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">Another featurette? Of course. More placeholder content here to give you an idea of how this layout would work with some actual real-world content in place.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 order-md-1">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>

      </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2 class="featurette-heading">And lastly, this one. <span class="text-muted">Checkmate.</span></h2>
        <p class="lead">And yes, this is the last block of representative placeholder content. Again, not really intended to be actually read, simply here to give you a better view of what this would look like with some actual content. Your content.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text></svg>

      </div>
    </div>

    <hr class="featurette-divider">

    <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->

  </div><!-- /.container -->


  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <footer class="container">
    <p class="float-end"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
    <p>&copy; 2017–2021 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
  </footer>
</main>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-JEW9xMcG8R+pH31jmWH6WWP0WintQrMb4s7ZOdauHnUtxwoG2vI5DkLtS3qm9Ekf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Video here: https://twitter.com/aclark4life/status/1383046678400339970

Comment: Can you post enough of your HTML code so the problem can be recreated?

Comment: Thanks @RichDeBourke I added a snippet above and here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aclark4life/41po8k7q/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup currently has a gradient over the carousel that goes from 90% black on the left to transparent on the right (so the left side of the image is almost black). The problem is, while the carousel is stationary, the caption is easy to read, when the slides are transitioning, the caption drops to below the gradient.

I think this is because when the carousel item is moving, it’s moving because it’s set to: `transform: translateX(100%);’ When an element has transform set to anything other than` none,` it creates a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).

What about applying the gradient to the carousel-items? I modified your code to use a separate gradient on each image so you can see the effect.

The carousel-caption divisions use position absolute with a z-index of 1, so when stationary, the text is over the gradient, but for reasons I don’t understand, the text moves below the gradient during transitions, but is above the gradient when stationary.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<style>
    /* GLOBAL STYLES
-------------------------------------------------- */
    /* Padding below the footer and lighter body text */

    body {
        padding-top: 3rem;
        padding-bottom: 3rem;
        color: #5a5a5a;
    }


    /* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */

    /* Carousel base class */
    .carousel {
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
    }

    /* Since positioning the image, we need to help out the caption */
    .carousel-caption {
        bottom: 3rem;
        z-index: 10;
    }

    /* Declare heights because of positioning of img element */
    .carousel-item {
        height: 32rem;
    }

    .carousel-item>img {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        min-width: 100%;
        height: 32rem;
    }


    /* MARKETING CONTENT
-------------------------------------------------- */

    /* Center align the text within the three columns below the carousel */
    .marketing .col-lg-4 {
        margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .marketing h2 {
        font-weight: 400;
    }

    /* rtl:begin:ignore */
    .marketing .col-lg-4 p {
        margin-right: .75rem;
        margin-left: .75rem;
    }

    /* rtl:end:ignore */


    /* Featurettes
------------------------- */

    .featurette-divider {
        margin: 5rem 0;
        /* Space out the Bootstrap <hr> more */
    }

    /* Thin out the marketing headings */
    .featurette-heading {
        font-weight: 300;
        line-height: 1;
        /* rtl:remove */
        letter-spacing: -.05rem;
    }


    /* RESPONSIVE CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */

    @media (min-width: 40em) {

        /* Bump up size of carousel content */
        .carousel-caption p {
            margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
            font-size: 1.25rem;
            line-height: 1.4;
        }

        .featurette-heading {
            font-size: 50px;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 62em) {
        .featurette-heading {
            margin-top: 7rem;
        }
    }


    .navbar-brand {
        margin: 0.4em 0 0.5em 0;
    }

    body>div.block.block-inverse.p-3>div>nav>a>h4 {
        letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    }

    .nav-item {
        font-family: "Work sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 500;
        letter-spacing: 0.05em;
        line-height: 2;
        padding-left: 0.5em;
        padding-right: 0.5em;
    }

    .carousel-caption {
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .carousel-item::after {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        background: linear-gradient(to right, black, transparent);
        z-index: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0.9;
    }

    #testimonials:after {
        position: absolute;
        content: "";
        background: linear-gradient(to right, black, transparent);
        z-index: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0.9;
    }

    .testimonial {
        padding: 14em 0 14em 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
</style>

<header>
    <div class="block block-inverse p-3" style="background-color: #3883AC;
        background-image: url({% static 'img/startup-1.jpg' %});
        background-position: -40px 0px;
        background-repeat: repeat-x;">

        <div class="container">


            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Carousel</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <form class="d-flex">
                            <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>


        </div>
    </div>

</header>

<main>

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/A00/fff.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="temp">
                <div class="carousel-caption text-start">
                    <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide of the carousel.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/A00/fff.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="temp">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide of the carousel.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/A00/fff.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="temp">
                <div class="carousel-caption text-end">
                    <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide of this carousel.</p>
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>


    <!-- Marketing messaging and featurettes
================================================== -->
    <!-- Wrap the rest of the page in another container to center all the content. -->

    <div class="container marketing">

        <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
                    <title>Placeholder</title>
                    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777" /><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text>
                </svg>

                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the three columns of text below the carousel. This is the first column.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
                    <title>Placeholder</title>
                    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777" /><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text>
                </svg>

                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Another exciting bit of representative placeholder content. This time, we've moved on to the second column.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle" width="140" height="140" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 140x140" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
                    <title>Placeholder</title>
                    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777" /><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em">140x140</text>
                </svg>

                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>And lastly this, the third column of representative placeholder content.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->


        <!-- START THE FEATURETTES -->

        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <div class="row featurette">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h2 class="featurette-heading">First featurette heading. <span class="text-muted">It’ll blow your mind.</span></h2>
                <p class="lead">Some great placeholder content for the first featurette here. Imagine some exciting prose here.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
                    <title>Placeholder</title>
                    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee" /><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text>
                </svg>

            </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <div class="row featurette">
            <div class="col-md-7 order-md-2">
                <h2 class="featurette-heading">Oh yeah, it’s that good. <span class="text-muted">See for yourself.</span></h2>
                <p class="lead">Another featurette? Of course. More placeholder content here to give you an idea of how this layout would work with some actual real-world content in place.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 order-md-1">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
                    <title>Placeholder</title>
                    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee" /><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text>
                </svg>

            </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <div class="row featurette">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h2 class="featurette-heading">And lastly, this one. <span class="text-muted">Checkmate.</span></h2>
                <p class="lead">And yes, this is the last block of representative placeholder content. Again, not really intended to be actually read, simply here to give you a better view of what this would look like with some actual content. Your content.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <svg class="bd-placeholder-img bd-placeholder-img-lg featurette-image img-fluid mx-auto" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 500x500" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false">
                    <title>Placeholder</title>
                    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#eee" /><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#aaa" dy=".3em">500x500</text>
                </svg>

            </div>
        </div>

        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <!-- /END THE FEATURETTES -->

    </div><!-- /.container -->


    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <footer class="container">
        <p class="float-end"><a href="#">Back to top</a></p>
        <p>&copy; 2017–2021 Company, Inc. &middot; <a href="#">Privacy</a> &middot; <a href="#">Terms</a></p>
    </footer>
</main>
```

Comment: Looks good! Will give it a try and report back, thanks again

Comment: Works great, much appreciated